# Java regular expression to JavaCC

Tags: java, regex, javacc

I have the string bellow(*) and I need to parse It with Java CC.

Initial string: (*)

```
    SPECIAL_STEP=\/file1\/file_1\/plugins\/plugin_folder\/folder1|
\/folder/subfolder|
\/stebs_folder\/cancan_folder|
\/fis_alb\/|
\/special_folder[^d].*|
\/.*_self_folder\/|
\/.*_conditional\/|

[step888#hrhkrtmlkhd]
FUNCTIONS=grregerg
```

I need to extract next substring:

```
`SPECIAL_STEP=\/file1\/file_1\/plugins\/plugin_folder\/folder1|
\/folder/subfolder|
\/stebs_folder\/cancan_folder|
\/fis_alb\/|
\/special_folder[^d].*|
\/.*_self_folder\/|
\/.*_conditional\/|`
```

I need to extract It without word "[step"; and to keep the same word("[step") into input stream.

When I use Java regular expresion It is simple but I need a solution to obtain the same result using JavaCC

In Java I have the folowing regular expresion: `SPECIAL_STEP=[^=]*(?=\r?\n\[step))`.

I need to do the same thing now in JavaCC, but I don't know if is posible to have positive lookahead in JavaCC.

Comment: Why? You don't need a full-blown parser generator to parse a regular expression. You're using a hammer to crack a nut.

Comment: This sample is a part from a huge file who is parsed with JavaCC. I use JavaCC to build a tree who represent that file (contains a lot of functionalities).

Comment: It looks like you have a line oriented format. I would recognize each line of data as a separate token and then catenate the images of all the lines that correspond to one item of data.